# Why does registryKey.GetValue still read the old value after I changed the rgistry with regedit.exe?

Tags: vb.net, registry

So I access the registry value with this code:

```
Dim dm2 As RegistryKey
Dim dm2Value As String = 0

dm2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Libralex\DM")
If dm2 IsNot Nothing Then
    dm2Value = DirectCast(dm2.GetValue("DM2"), String)
End If
```

Originally I had "1" stored as the value under DM2, and it worked fine :) So then I closed the program and changed the value of DM2 to "2" with regedit.exe, but I kept getting "1" from dm2.getValue :( I thought maybe restarting would fix the problem, but then I still got a "1" from dm2.GetValue while regedit.exe told me I have a 2 stored there.

What am I doing wrong?

Envirnment Info:
Visual Studio 2010 on 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: Use regedit.exe and navigate to Software\Wow6432Node\Libralex\DM.  If you see it then tinker with the Platform target setting in the Advanced compile options.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, this answers my question. Please write it as an answer below so I can accept it.